# div alignments in equal height in style with CSS

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have to section in page , but there are not alignment in height and center
How can I centered in a middle of page and with same alignment in height
these are 2 different dive , one of them a profile section, the others are photos of profile
but they are not exactly in the middle of page with same height

```
<div class="container">

<div class="row  ">

    <!-- Mom Profile -->


    <div class="   col-md-3 col-sm-12 py-6  ">
        <div class="card card-profile card-secondary">
            <div class="card-header" style="background-image: url(assets/img/blogpost.jpg)">

                <div class="profile-picture center-align">
                    <div class="avatar avatar-xl">
                        <img src="assets/img/profile.jpg" alt="..." class="avatar-img rounded-circle">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body  ">
                <div class="user-profile text-center">

                    <div class="desc">Ege</div>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <div class="row user-stats text-center">
                    <div class="col">
                        <div class=" ">125</div>
                        <div class=" ">Score</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <div class=" ">25</div>
                        <div class=" accordion-danger">Sell</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">

                        <div class=" ">134</div>
                        <div class="">Meal</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <!-- Image Gallery -->
     

        <div   class="py-6 mt-5 col-md-9 col-sm-12">

            <div class="card">

                <div class="body">
                    <div id="aniimated-thumbnials" class="list-unstyled row clearfix">
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <a href="img/1.jpg" data-sub-html="Demo Description">
                                <img class="img-responsive thumbnail" src="img/thumb/thumb-1.jpg">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <a href="img/2.jpg" data-sub-html="Demo Description">
                                <img class="img-responsive thumbnail" src="img/thumb/thumb-2.jpg">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <a href="img/3.jpg" data-sub-html="Demo Description">
                                <img class="img-responsive thumbnail" src="img/thumb/thumb-3.jpg">
                            </a>
                        </div>



                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
   
    </div>

</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please add some images or screenshots for more clarification?

Comment: @Prashant off course , I update it , I want to have 2 section tag, but I can not , because for back end code it is better i thinks, I want to have 2 view component later, but now I want to fix the front of it

Comment: Would like to see what you've tried with CSS by giving the css styling

Comment: @masoudmazloum This means you want right-side images to be set to the vertical middle of the left-side div or all the above sections to be set center of the page?

Comment: @Prashant I want all of them be a center but each section give to a section tag, more over, under both of them will be a table to show some food in a row. I want all of them have a center alignment

Comment: @Richie the page have 3 section , I want have 3 section tag , that have separate section for better design and better back end code, and all of them have aligntment with center

Answer (score 0):

For the below code, you can see that all of your sections are in the center and middle of the page. I have added dummy images for your reference; please change them. Use the below code to fulfill your requirements.

```
<section class="main d-flex align-items-center vh-100">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row  ">
            <!-- Mom Profile -->
            <div class="   col-md-3 col-sm-12 py-6  ">
                <div class="card card-profile card-secondary">
                    <div class="card-header" style="background-image: url(assets/img/blogpost.jpg)">
                        <div class="profile-picture center-align">
                            <div class="avatar avatar-xl text-center">
                                <img src="https://picsum.photos/100/100" alt="..." class="avatar-img rounded-circle">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body  ">
                        <div class="user-profile text-center">
                            <div class="desc">Ege</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-footer">
                        <div class="row user-stats text-center">
                            <div class="col">
                                <div class=" ">125</div>
                                <div class=" ">Score</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col">
                                <div class=" ">25</div>
                                <div class=" accordion-danger">Sell</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col">
                                <div class=" ">134</div>
                                <div class="">Meal</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Image Gallery -->
            <div class="py-6 col-md-9 col-sm-12">
                <div class="card h-100">
                    <div class="body h-100">
                        <div id="aniimated-thumbnials" class="list-unstyled row clearfix p-3 h-100">
                            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 overflow-hidden">
                                <a href="img/1.jpg" data-sub-html="Demo Description">
                                    <img class="img-responsive thumbnail w-100 h-100" src="https://picsum.photos/300/150" alt="test">
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 overflow-hidden">
                                <a href="img/2.jpg" data-sub-html="Demo Description">
                                    <img class="img-responsive thumbnail w-100 h-100" src="https://picsum.photos/300/150" alt="test">
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 overflow-hidden">
                                <a href="img/3.jpg" data-sub-html="Demo Description">
                                    <img class="img-responsive thumbnail w-100 h-100" src="https://picsum.photos/300/150" alt="test">
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: but this code is not responsive in small screen, _ I mean the photo of galley is not and shoes in a very small size, which part of cod I had to change for this issu?

Comment: and I want to be in the top middle of page , becuase I want to take a table under both of them